# Unable to switch mapviews using ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, android-mapview, illegalstateexception, viewswitcher

I am trying to use `ViewSwitcher` to switch between two `MapView` objects (GIS based). But I get the following exception at `magnifyMap (**line xyz**) mapview` :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

even after removing the child views (`MapViews`) from the parent layout (`homeScreenLayout`). Following are the relevant snippets.

1) My 1st `MapView` is in XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/homeScreenLayout">

<MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</MapView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

2) My 2nd `MapView` is in my Activity:

```
        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        MapView magnifyMap = new MapView(ActivityMap.this);
        magnifyMap = _map;
        magnifyMap.setExtent(new Envelope(_tappedPoint, 3.0, 3.0));
```

3) I am using `ViewSwitcher` to add these 2 views:

```
        homeScreenLayout.removeView(map);
        homeScreenLayout.removeView(magnifyMap);

        ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(ActivityMap.this);
        homeScreenLayout.addView(viewSwitcher);

        viewSwitcher.addView(map, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        // **line xyz**
        viewSwitcher.addView(magnifyMap, 1, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); // line xyz

        viewSwitcher.showNext();
```

Comment: You can only have 1 mapview per activity. Anything you do here will definitely be a hack.

Comment: @Falmarri - I am trying to build a magnify tool. How can I achieve it without having 2 mapview objects in the same activity? Is there a way where I can show one of them as an image?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot have more than one MapView objects in a single ArcGIS based Android application. Hence, we cannot use ViewSwitcher to accomplish this task.